# what is __format in printf definition exactly mean / does?

Tags: c

please could you help me understand what's __format in printf prototype for?

extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);

How can I find set of these in documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: `__format` used as parameter variable name.

Comment: check out the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 declaration,

`int printf(const char * restrict format, ... );`

using the `__` is a variable nomenclature.

Comment: Actually, it's a [reserved name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Note: C11dr 7.1.3 1 Reserved identifiers " ... All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use. ..."

Comment: If `stdio.h` had had `int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);` and the including `.c` file had defined `format` as an object-like macro, the header would break. By using `__format` they avoid the problem, as much as you can in C, because the application isn't allowed to define names that begin with two underscores.  Similarly for `restrict` when the compiler is in C89 mode (this relies on a common extension where keywords added in C99 are available with and without two leading underscores, and remain available with the underscores in C89 mode).